# Sorting a hash of hash refs

Tags: perl

I have a hash (`test`) of hash refs:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my %test = (
    110 => { 'foobar' => '3.09' },
    119 => { 'foobar' => '2.08' },
    118 => { 'foobar' => '2.18' },
);

for my $key ( keys %test ) {
    print( "$key, $test{$key}->{'foobar'}\n" );
}
```

#### output

```
110, 3.09
119, 2.08
118, 2.18
```

But sorting is a problem:

```
my @sorted = sort { $test{$a}->{'foobar'} cmp $test{$b}->{'foobar'} } keys %test;

Use of uninitialized value in string comparison (cmp) at ...
```

What's wrong?

```
$ perl -version
This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for i386-openbsd
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the sample data you showed. Have you inspected your *actual* data for `undef` values, nonexistent `foobar` keys, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the mistake. I had defined two variables `$a` and `$b` in top of the script and assigned the value "0" to them. In the case above this leads Perl's `sort` to this error message. In case of using

```
my @sorted = sort { $a cmp $b } keys %test;
```

the error message becomes more clearer:

```
"my $a" used in sort comparison at ...
"my $b" used in sort comparison at ...
```

This error message was the hint to the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sort` code works fine with the data you have shown, except that `cmp` should probably be `<=>`

In future, please dump a *reference* to aggregate variables:

```
print Dumper \%test
```

Comment: String comparisons may actually be preferable in some cases, e.g. for some kinds of [version numbers](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$]).

Comment: @haukex: That's why I wrote *probably*. It is very rare that numeric values should be treated as non-decimal, and the idea is distracting and confusing for most people.